# Google sing in ANDROID. Error: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4

Tags: android, google-signin

I have this error:

```
07-04 16:39:07.881  22117-22117/net.simplifiedcoding.androidlogin I/android-plus-quickstart﹕ onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4

statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED
```

and my code is:
[click here](http://pastebin.com/J2AJ1CKm)

please help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out step 3 in the tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started